# Is there a format like ONNX for persisting data pre-processing / feature-engineering pipelines without serializing?

Tags: python, machine-learning, serialization, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I'm looking for a way to save my [sklearn Pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) for data pre-processing so that I can re-load it to make predictions.

So far I've only seen options like [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) or [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.dump.html), that will serialize arbitrary python objects, but the resulting file

1. is opaque if I wanted to store the pipeline in version control,
2. will serialize *any* python object and therefore might not be safe to unserialize, and
3. may run into issues with different Python version or library versions

It seems like [ONNX](https://onnx.ai/) is a great way to save models in a safe & interoperable way -- Is there any alternative for data pre-processing pipelines?

Comment: It seems like ONNX already can do that?  
http://onnx.ai/sklearn-onnx/pipeline.html

But also there's [PMML](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml) and [PFA](http://dmg.org/pfa/docs/motivation/).